# Negative cointegration

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I am new to the topic of cointegration and my question might be trivial.

Let's say $X_t$ is an increasing series and $Y_t$ is a decreasing series; is it possible that they will be cointegrated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As long as $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are integrated series and their integration order is the same (e.g. I(1)), they may be cointegrated.

$X_t$ and $Y_t$ may each contain a deterministic time trend. The deterministic time trend(s) should be accounted for when considering cointegration. There might be a need to include a deterministic time trend $\tau$ into the cointegration vector so that a linear combination of $X_t$, $Y_t$ and $\tau$ would be integrated to a lower order than $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are (e.g. $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are I(1) but a linear combination of $X_t$, $Y_t$ and $\tau$ is I(0)).

Example: suppose $Z_t$ is a random walk, $\varepsilon_{1,t}$ and $\varepsilon_{2,t}$ are stationary processes, and $c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive constants. Define

$$X_t:=Z_t+c_1 t+\varepsilon_{1,t}$$
$$Y_t:=Z_t-c_2 t+\varepsilon_{2,t}$$

It can be seen that

1. $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are integrated of order one (I(1));
2. they have linear time trends with opposite signs ($X_t$ has a positive time trend, $Y_t$ has a negative time trend);
3. $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are cointegrated since their linear combination (with a linear time trend included) $X_t-Y_t-(c_1-c_2)t=\varepsilon_{1,t}-\varepsilon_{2,t}$ is stationary.

Comment: Are you sure they could still be cointegrated despite having an opposite time trend, I am not sure how a trend in the cointegration would deal with the different trends? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou, I included an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I saw many of your posts on cointegration/time series, great to have you on this site!

Comment: Thanks, @Matifou! This site has helped me a lot in learning about cointegration and many other topics. I also appreciate your contributions (I have noticed them before), so I can only return the compliment!